# Black Water in Fluid Sim

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am making a fluid sim with blender 2.77 (same result in 2.79) in cycles render. Water flows from a pipe into a pool and there are a few obstacles etc.

Now I have an issue if I set the quality factor high (100, 120, 150, 200) always the same result with different forms. Here the picture:
Quality 200, 1-2 Subdivisions, 1.0-1.5 smoothing :
[image]

The former picture looks good, though it still has the black shadow on the inflow water.
Quality 80, 1 Subdivision, 1.0 smoothing

I am trying to get rid of the black spots/shadows in the water.
The lighning is done mainly by the world and one lamp.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: can you please [attach the blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: I solved the issue with the black stripe in the pool. I changed the container of the water domain from "both" to "shell" in the "Volume Initialization" settings. But still have issues with the inflow.

Comment: I am only allowed to post two links. So I deleted the second picture.

Answer (score 1):

I solved both issues:

1, Getting rid of the black "stripe": Setting the container (the concrete surrounding the water) in the fluid simulation under the "Volume Initialization" settings from "both" --> "shell".
[image]

2, Getting rid of the black surface of the water inflow:
Setting the amount of "max bounces" at least at 8.

[image]

It is still not perfect, but definately an improvement.